# Chrome extension interaction with React SPA failed to inject code after component re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am able to inject custom html code with chrome extension into a React webpage for table rows components with `ExecuteScript`, however, when users is changing the pagination and table is re-rendered, I would like to run the `ExecuteScript` again in order to inject for the new rows, however I am not able to catch the update since the webpage would not change and React is doing the virtual DOM changes. Is there a way to overcome this issue? I don't have the ability to change the React code (for instance to add some event dispatcher), looking for another ways.

Comment: If you see a change on the screen, this means the actual DOM has changed, and you can catch it with a MutationObserver on the root element of the react app (typically `<div id="root"></div>`). Virtual DOM just stands in the middle to allow rerendering a heavy DOM tree while only updating the diff in the actual DOM.

Comment: @Noam super! it is correct. Write it as an answer so I can close the question please.

Comment: I don't have the time now to work out the details for an actual answer, and you can't close the question anyway other than deleting it. However, you are more than welcome to work out an answer yourself based on my comment, and post it for the benefit of others.